# Gradient flow of harmonic function is measure preserving?

Tags: geometry, analysis, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a manifold with $Ric \ge  - \left( {n - 1} \right)$ and $f:{B_R}\left( p \right) \to R$ is a lipschitz and harmonic function. In a paper, it says "As the gradient flow ${\Phi _t}$ of $f$ is measure preserving." Gradient flow of harmonic function is measure preserving? Suppose $U$ is a subset of $M$, $V = {\Phi _t}\left( U \right)$.$$Vol\left( V \right) = \int_V {1dx}  = \int_U {Jacobi\left( {y = {\Phi _t}\left( x \right)} \right)} dy $$$Jacobi\left( {y = {\Phi _t}\left( U \right)} \right) = 1$? I don't know how to compute.

Answer (score 3):

A flow is measure-preserving if and only if the [divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form#Divergence) of the vector field is zero.  Thus, a gradient flow is measure-preserving if and only if the original function is harmonic.

Comment: :Thank you!But I don't quite understand "if and only if the divergence of the vector field is zero".Please explain it in detail or introduce a reference book.And I am also troubled by the computation of the Jacobi.Yet this is another way to understand the question.

Comment: @user34233 See [Proposition 16.33 in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*](http://books.google.com/books?id=xygVcKGPsNwC&pg=PA424) for the theorem on divergence.